# Directory_ExpiredPageToken when looping through response without delay

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am accessing Microsoft Graph using PowerShell which is working like a charm, except paging.

From time to time I get `Directory_ExpiredPageToken` errors. The errors are mostly gone if I set a 1 sec delay between the requests.

```
$ReturnObject = @()
while ($Uri.Length -gt 0) {
    Add-TraceLine -Type DEBUG -Text "Calling '$($Uri)'"
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
    $ReturnObject += $Response
    if ($Response.'@odata.nextlink') {
        $Uri = $Response.'@odata.nextlink'
        #Delay needed, otherwise Directory_ExpiredPageToken errors occured
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000
    }
    else {
        $Uri = $null
    }
}
```

Any idea whats going on here?

The delay is a workaround to get the workflow running which is using this module. But I want to get rid of it because of performance reason.

EDIT:

This is a JSON response simplified (value is not only one object, but an array) and changed a little bit because of privacy/security reasons:

```
{
"@odata.context":  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(department,displayName,ext2j5y6eqq_linkeduser,givenName,id,jobTitle,mail,mailNickname,surname,userPrincipalName)",
"@odata.nextLink":  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userType+eq+%27Guest%27\u0026$select=department%2cdisplayName%2cext2j5y6eqq_linkeduser%2cgivenName%2cid%2cjobTitle%2cmail%2cmailNickname%2csurname%2cuserPrincipalName\u0026$skiptoken=RFNwdAkAAQAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADzX_JYCsThFmyry6_Ndz8kBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAXMS4yLjg0MC4xMTM1NTYuMS40LjIzMzECAAAAAAABJruiMN_CtUmk63sXDRMMdg",
"value":  [
              {
                  "id":  "80f7fa19-2669-470d-86ac-ee4c052a5186",
                  "department":  null,
                  "displayName":  "XC Admin",
                  "givenName":  "XC",
                  "jobTitle":  null,
                  "mail":  null,
                  "mailNickname":  "xcadmin",
                  "surname":  "Admin",
                  "userPrincipalName":  "xcadmin@domain.onmicrosoft.com"
              }
          ]
}
```

EDIT:

This is the error response

```
+         ERROR   { throw $Line }
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (11.04.2018-06:5...
}
}
}:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 11.04.2018-06:50:13: <ERROR> - Get-User: {
"error": {
"code": "Directory_ExpiredPageToken",
"message": "The specified page token value has expired and can no longer be included in your request.",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "13ecca81-2d8c-4d0f-a58e-4a9cdd72e100",
  "date": "2018-04-11T04:50:15"
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the actual JSON response you're getting?

Comment: I added a sample to my post

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I was looking for the `Directory_ExpiredPageToken` response you were getting.

Comment: Sorry - added above

Comment: I'm struggling to replicate this behavior. Be that as it may, have you tried a smaller time frame? I'm wondering if 250 or 500 ms would be enough.

Comment: Yes - 500ms was not enough. This morning even 1 sec was not enough and I faced it, but just 1 time. The workflow runs every hour.

Comment: If you're running this every hour, you should really consider using `/delta`. A delta query will only return the changes since the last time you ran it rather than pulling the entire list every time.

Comment: I know the delta queries, but its not possible here. The whole workflow replicates changes between several Azure AD Forests - Delta Queries are used for reading users in source, but as I dont use any staging I need to get the whole set of users in target for comparison.